# Tomcat7 WAR unpack incomplete

Tags: tomcat7, war

I am running Tomcat 7.0.23 on CentOS 6.2. I have a WAR I deploy using a server specific context XML file.

*conf/server.xml* contains:

```
<Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
```

*conf/Catalina/localhost/MyWebapp.xml* contains:

```
<Context docBase="/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.23/MyWebapp.war" unpackWAR="true">
```

The WAR file contains (I verified it by unzipping it):

```
css/style.css
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/maven/...
WEB-INF/classes/... (the .class files)
WEB-INF/lib/... (some .jar files)
WEB-INF/resources/...
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/log4j.xml
```

When deployed in tomcat (either using hot deployment or cold deployment, both with previously deleting the MyWebapp folder) the *work/Catalina/localhost/MyWebapp/* folder only contains:

```
WEB-INF/classes/...
WEB-INF/lib/...
```

The [Tomcat 7 Host Documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/host.html#Standard_Implementation) for the parameter *unpackWARs* says:

```
Set to true if you want web applications that are placed in the appBase directory as web application archive (WAR) files to be unpacked into a corresponding disk directory structure, false to run such web applications directly from a WAR file.
```

So it's not very specific on what it actually unpacks.

Is it expected behavior that Tomcat does not unpack the entire WAR file? Is that documented and where? Where should I put resource files instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a strange behavior in the Tomcat versions 7.0.12 - 7.0.47.
The [changelog](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html) for version 7.0.12 contains:

```
Don't unpack WAR files if they are not located in the Host's appBase.
```

And for version 7.0.48 (released as 7.0.50):

```
Add support for unpacking WARs located outside of the Host's appBase in to the appBase.
```

For further information on these changes see the corresponding [Bugzilla entry](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=51294).